# Script that executes ssh-add and feeds the passphrase automatically

Tags: git, bash, ssh

I'm using a script that executes

```
eval `ssh-agent`
ssh-add
```

which prompts you to input your SSH passphrase. Is it possible to input the passphrase from the script? The goal of this is to open connection to git repo whenever I open GitBash without having to constantly input my passphrase. I know putting passphrase in a script is terrible security, but I really don't care. I'm doing for testing.

Comment: With aah-agent, you'll enter password only once... And it will be better: 1. do it 2. by hand

Comment: GitBash means "Windows", yes?

Comment: Yes, it's a git console for windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're going to do that you'd be better off just not using a passphrase on the key. In which case you wouldn't even need to use `ssh-agent`. You can change or remove a passphrase from an existing key with `ssh-keygen -p`.

Comment: What happens when I eventually want to use a password?

Comment: The same command can be used to set a password again. Although it would probably be better to generate a new key at that point, and consider the old key as compromised.

Comment: I don't mean for that. I mean it doesn't help with the fact that I don't want to have to enter the password every time manually.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - with ssh-agent you'll enter password only once **per session** (for any amount of pull/push)

Comment: With the passphrase removed from the key, there would be no passphrase to enter.

Comment: Yes of course, it achieves what I want temporarily. Once I choose to have a password though I'm still stuck with manually inputting it to ssh-add. Remember gitbash doesn't run inside Window cmd console, but in its own environment.

Comment: Yes, if you want to use a passphrase, you need to enter it. Otherwise there isn't really any point to having it.

Answer (score 10):

Answer how to do it is here:

https://ifireball.wordpress.com/2015/01/12/automatic-loading-of-ssh-keys-from-scripts/

Summary:

```
echo "exec cat" > ap-cat.sh
chmod a+x ap-cat.sh
export DISPLAY=1
echo $MY_SSH_PASS | SSH_ASKPASS=./ap-cat.sh ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
rm ap-cat.sh
```

**Note:** you need to export the `DISPLAY` environment variable to some value.

Comment: Actually, it worked for me with `SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/bin/cat`.

Comment: @rominf I don't know how it can work directly as it tries to interpret the `'Enter passphrase...` as file.  It should not work that way.

Comment: You will get `/usr/bin/cat: 'Enter passphrase for id_test: ': No such file or directory`

Comment: Perfect! For Windows Gitbash, not need for `export DISPLAY=1`.
`SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/bin/cat` not working